# TestNG execute compiled tests in jar file

Tags: maven, testng

I have a testNG test class which runs fine, but when i package it into a jar file with test files included, i am unable to run the tests from it. The jar file contains the test.class file in it. When i invoke the test from maven it returns "no tests to run".

Any suggestion on how to run a test class within a jar using testNG?

Comment: could you include the contents of your jar file ?

Answer (score -1):

Can you open the jar file with winrar and see if everything is packed there?
Also, is testng your application entry point? What happens when you write:

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

in console? You should see testng output.
Also, are you sure your parameter xml file is pointing to the right class and that it works?

Are your classes in the jar file? the classes with your tests? Please check that with winrar to see the jar content.

I think that with this checklist your tests should run.